# Building a cron job scheduler

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron

Currently I'm trying to build a good scheduler system as an interface for setting and editing cron jobs on my system. My system is built using Zend framework 1.11.11 on a Linux server.

I have 2 main problems that I want your suggestion for:

**Problem 1: The setup of the application itself**

I have 2 ways to run the cron job:

1. First way is to create a folder `scripts` and create a common bootstrap file in it where I'll load only the resources that I need. Then for each task I'll create a separate script and in each script I'll include the bootstrap file. Finally, I'll add a cron task in the crontab file for each one of these scripts and the task will be something like `***** php /path/to/scripts/folder/cronScript_1.php` .
2. Secondly treat the cron job like a normal request (no special bootstrap). Add a cron task in the crontab file for each one of these scripts and the task will be something like `***** curl http://www.mydomain.com/module/controller/action` .

**Problem 2: The interface to the application**

Adding a cron job also can be done in 2 ways:

1. For each task there will be an entry in the crontab file. when I want to add a new task I must do it via cPanel or any other means to edit the crontab (which might not be available).
2. Store the tasks in the database and provide a UI for interacting with the database (grid to add few tasks and configuration). After that write only 1 cron job in the crontab file that runs every minute. This job will select all jobs from the database and checks if there is a job that should be run now (the time for the tasks will be stored and compared with the current time of the server).

---

In your opinion which way is better to implement for each part? Is there a ready made solution for this that is better in general??

**Note**

I came across [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) will searching for a ready made solution. Is this what I'm looking for or is it something totally different?

Thanks.

Comment: Quartz is for java so I don't think that will be an easy task to integrate with zend-framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just my opinion, but I personally like both 1 & 2 dependent on what your script is intending to accomplish.  For instance, we mostly do 1 with all of our cron entries as it becomes really easy to look at /etc/crontab and see at a glance when things are supposed to run. However, there are times when a script needs to be called every minute because logic within the script will then figure out what to run in that exact minute. (i.e. millions of users that need to be processed continually so you have a formula for what users to do in each minute of the hour)

Also take a look at Gearman (http://gearman.org/). It enables you to have cron scripts running on one machine that then slice up the jobs into smaller bits and farm those bits out to other servers for processing. You have full control over how far you want to take the map/reduce aspect of it. It has helped us immensely and allows us to process thousands of algorithm scripts per minute. If we need more power we just spin up more "workhorse" nodes and Gearman automatically detects and utilizes them.

We currently do everything on the command line and don't use cPanel, Plesk, etc. so I can't attest to what it's like editing the crontab from one of those backends. You may want to consider having one person be the crontab "gatekeeper" on your team. Throw the expected crontab entries into a non web accessible folder in your project code. Then whenever a change to the file is pushed to version control that person is expected to SSH into the appropriate machine and make the changes. I am not sure of your internal structure so this may or may not be feasible, but it's a good idea for developers to be able to see the way(s) that crontab will be executing scripts.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the detailed answer :) will definitely look into Gearman! I have a question though, What if I'm doing a project on a shared hosting where I won't have the freedom to manipulate the server to my needs? will Gearman be a good solution or I'll have to build a customized system inside my application?

Comment: @Songo I've only ever implemented on my own hardware or dedicated servers with root access. I don't think you will be able to use it in a shared environment unless you have root access.

Answer (score 0):

For *Problem 2: The interface to the application* I've used both methods 1 & 2.  I strongly recommend the 2nd one. It will take quite more upfront work creating the database tables and building the UI. In the long run though, it will make it much easier adding new jobs to be run. I build the UI for my current company and it's so easy to use that non-technical people (accountants, warehouse supervisors) are able to go in and create jobs.

Much easier than logging onto the server as root, editing crontab, remembering the patterns and saving.  Plus you won't be known as "The crontab guy" who everyone comes to whenever they want to add something to crontab.

As for setting up the application itself, I would have cron call one script and have that script run the rest.  That way you only need 1 cron entry.  Just be aware that if running the jobs takes a long time, you need to make sure that the script only starts running if there are no other instances running.  Otherwise you may end up with the same job running twice.